# Python and Win10 - run command and repeat when finished

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I am currently using `os.system('start cmd.exe /k ' + command)`
where “command” is a string that opens an exe file with some arguments.
I know I could avoid calling cmd.exe, but to me it’s easier with that.

When the executable stops, cmd doesn’t close and remains idle waiting for another command; what I want to do is: when the execution finishes, make my python script call the same command again in the same cmd window.

EDIT: I am running multiple instances of cmd.exe which open the same exe with different parameters, my aim is to do the same as above for every instance

```py
returncode = os.system(mycommand)
print(returncode)
```

prints “0” just after running cmd (without waiting for the execution to end)

I don’t really need the exit code, but parsing the text output from the window might be useful to know whether to stop looping the command or just wait some time before running it again

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to run `command` in an infinite loop in CMD? Do you need the output/exit code from `command`?

Comment: so does the os.system(....) call return in those cases?

Comment: _It remain waiting_ is because you are telling it too. Type `cmd /?` for help.

Comment: Yes, @Mark I know that, I am using /k on purpose to keep the window open, the reason why I am using it is that I want to re-execute the command in the same window

Comment: You can't without typing. Edit your question with the actual problem.

Comment: The usage of `os.system` is deprecated. The Python documentation recommends to use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). You are describing an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It looks like you want to run several console applications one after the other with showing the output of all those executables in one console window. The best approach for this task would be using the `subprocess` module to run one executable after the other without `cmd.exe` directly from within Python script, capture `stdout` and `stderr` and output them with the Python script.

Comment: If the output of the executables do not need to be modified by the Python script before writing them to console, it is possible to use `stdout=PIPE` and `stderr=PIPE` to redirect the standard output and the error output of the executed application directly to `stdout` and `stderr` of Python executable processing the Python script. So what you want to achieve could be done with a simple loop in Python script running one application after the other with their arguments.